# Convert array on integers to a number, just like bit array

Tags: algorithm, converters

With an array of bits ( 0 or 1 values ), i can convert it to an integer and the use bitwise operations to manipulate it (check if one position is 0 or 1, switch 0 <-> 1). 
What would be a similar solution for an array of arbitrary integers?

For example, in a bit array a I can add a new bit by doing a shift: 
x << 1 adds a 0 bit at the end of x. 
For an array of arbitrary integers I can do something like:
(1, 2, 7) -> 127 and then to add 9 at the end I can do 127 * 10 + 9. 
But this procedure cannot work if i want to work say 11 (or any number with 2 or more digits) 
at the end.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it looks to me like in this case you will have to figure out the right multiplier to use before adding the new number.

For example, if you have the number 127 and want to append the number 98, you have to do it like this: `new_number = 127*100 + 98`, that is, you have to find how many digits `n` are in the new number, and multiply the other number by `10^n` before adding it.

Here's my implementation:

```
int array_to_number(int arr[], int size) {
  if (size == 0)
    return 0;
  int result = arr[0];
  int n;
  int i;
  int mul;
  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    for (n = arr[i], mul = 1; n; mul *= 10, n /= 10)
      ; /* Intentionally left blank */
    result = result*mul + arr[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

The second `for` is doing exactly what I explained; the rest of the code should be pretty much self explanatory.

Bear in mind, though, that this can easily overflow. You may want to change it to use unsigned integers, but still, this is very easy to overflow if you mess around with big arrays or arrays with very large integers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert a number given in [positional notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation).  To that end you need the digits, and the base.  In particular the base must be provided, because otherwise different interpretations are possible.  Consider e.g. `11`.  Without knowing the base it's not clear if this is an eleven (base 10) or three (base 2) or even seventeen (base 16).  So the base must be provided explicitly.  Given the base and the digits, for each digit you multiply the result so far by the base and add the digits.  For binary, base 2, this multiplication by two is identical to the left shift you mention.  Here is an example in Python:

```
def convert_number( digits, base ):
    result = 0
    for x in digits:
        result = result * base + x
    return result

print( convert_number( [1, 1, 0, 1], 2 )) #13
print( convert_number( [1, 1, 0, 1], 10 )) #1101
print( convert_number( [1, 1, 0, 1], 16 )) #4353
```